# Eigen - directly compute log determinant of huge sparse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, eigen

I would like to compute the log-determinant of a very large matrix (5e6 x 5e6). It is, however, highly sparse - there are only 6 nonzero entries on each row (7 counting the diagonal). It's also symmetrical and positive definite.

In Eigen I've tried to use the Cholesky decomposition: `SimplicialLDLT<SparseMatrix<double>>` followed by summing the log-values of the diagonal (accessible by `SimplicialLDLT::vectorD()`) But the decomposition runs for a very long time without finishing. Any better approaches? I don't actually need any sort of decomposition, just the log-determinant itself (or a good estimate).

Comment: For such a matrix, SimplicialLDLT should be pretty fast, of the order of 1-2s. Make sure you compiled with compiler optimizations ON, and that you properly filled the matrix.

Comment: Can you ascertain you are not hitting swap? I ask because, before investigating algorithms, maybe at some point for some reason Eigen is trying to densely fill a huge matrix?

Comment: Also, on what order are the sizes of the non-zero entries? I’m trying to create a similar array to test with, but I’m not sure if I should fill non-zero entries with uniform random data, or normal random data, or ones.

Comment: So in general, a symmetric matrix’s LU decomposition will have positive and negative elements along L or U’s diagonal. Are you taking care that, when you take log of the negative ones, you either keep the absolute value? or use a complex-capable log that returns a complex number that you then sum?

Comment: @AhmedFasih all the non-zero entries off-diagonal are -1. On diagonal they're small values between 1-5. Perhaps you're right that it's trying to make it dense but I'm not sure how to tell.

Comment: I would check Activity Monitor (OS X) or System Monitor (Ubuntu), etc., to see how much swap (‘page file’ in Windows) is being used. If the CPU usage by your program is pegged to 100% (or more), that’s indicative of it **not** hitting swap. If CPU usage of your app is low, then that’d suggest it was memory-bound (RAM or more likely disk/swap).

Comment: Couple of observations: (1) [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicSparseSystems.html) says `SimplicialLDLT` is recommended for *small* and *positive-definite*: your matrix is not at all small and is only symmetric (not positive definite!). Might try `SparseLU`: “optimized for … large problems with irregular patterns”—which sounds like your situation.

Comment: (2) I generated a matrix similar to yours but only 1e4 by 1e4 [in Matlab](https://gist.github.com/fasiha/e5a3b2774e6708bacc2952dbc6e810b8) and computed its [LDL' decomposition](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ldl.html) (which works for symmetric matrixes, no need for positive-definite). I see that the lower-triangular `L` is only ~10% sparse: 10596515 non-zero elements, and takes up 160 MB. If that usage scales up to 5e6 linearly, you’d be looking at 160 MB / 1e4 * 5e6, or 80 GB. If it scales up *quadratically*, it’s 160 MB / 1e4^2 * 5e6^2 = 40 TB memory .

Comment: @AhmedFasih I should have specified: it's actually positive definite. Sorry!

Comment: Can you describe an algorithm to generate a random matrix like yours, that has 1 ≤ d ≤ 5 on each diagonal element and six other entries per row, of -1, and which is positive definite?

Comment: @AhmedFasih It's the precision matrix of a Markov Model. Basically, there is an underlying grid of size NxN, and we construct the inverse covariance (==precision) directly, which has size N^2 x N^2. All points have self-precision of K (say, a small number). All neighboring points have -1 for their precision. So for each grid point, put a -1 for its four neighbors. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I might as well put this as an answer so I can show a figure.

**First,** Eigen’s [documentation on sparse solvers](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicSparseSystems.html) says `SimplicialLDLT` is “Recommended for very sparse and not too large problems”. Your problem is very sparse but also very large.

**Second,** [`SimplicialLDLT`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SimplicialLDLT.html) needs input to be not just symmetric (“selfadjoint”) but also positive definite, which yours is almost certainly not (unless you have reason to think otherwise?).

It’s possible that `SimplicialLDLT` is spending a ton of time computing the Cholesky factorization—which it won’t find successfully since your matrix isn’t positive definite.

That brings me to a **third** point. I generated, [in Matlab](https://gist.github.com/fasiha/e5a3b2774e6708bacc2952dbc6e810b8) , a small version of your problem: 1e4 by 1e4 sparse matrix, symmetric, with small integers on the diagonal between 1 and 5, and each row having six other entries of -1. Matlab’s equivalent of LDLT is [`ldl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ldl.html) and oddly enough doesn’t need a positive definite matrix, so it chewed through my 1e4 by 1e4 example in a few seconds (it takes longer for it to generate the sparse matrix than to factorize it into LDL').

Here’s the lower-triangular factor’s sparsity pattern (via `spy(L)` in Matlab):

[image: Lower-triangular factor’s sparsity pattern]

It has 1e7 non-zero elements, and takes up 162 MB RAM. Recall this is for a 1e4 by 1e4 problem. If memory usage scales linearly with the length of the matrix (1e4 → 5e6), you’re looking at nearly 80 GB RAM usage. If instead it scales with the number of elements (1e4^2 → 5e6^2), you’d need 38 TB RAM… None of this analysis is conclusive—it could well be that scaling to 5e6 by 5e6 greatly increases sparsity in LDL' factors, but this may explain why Eigen is hanging. As mentioned in comments, check if your swap file is thrashing.

A **fourth** issue is that, for my test example of 1e4 by 1e4, I have a lot of exactly-zero entries on the lower-triangular `L` matrix’s diagonal, so the determinant of the entire sparse matrix is zero to double-precision, logs or no logs.

Answer (score 0):

How fast do you expect? You could try all the sparse solvers in version 3.3-beta1 and find which one is faster for you problem.

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicSparseSystems.html